# For some cases, convert XHTML to docx with docx4j lose original style

Tags: ms-word, xhtml, docx4j

during my test, I find when converting following html content to docx, the original style will be lost.

1. `< a href="http://www.google.com">Google< /a>`

   result in docx: no underline.
2. `< p>< span style="text-decoration: underline;">underline text< /span>< /p>`

   result in docx: no underline
3. `< p>< span style="text-decoration: line-through;">delete text< /span>< /p>`

   result in docx: no delete line
4. `< p style="margin-left:30.0px;">indent text< /p>`

   result in docx: no any indent
5. `< h1>header line< /h1>`

   result in docx: only plain text
6. `< p>< span style="background-color: rgb(255,255,0);">background color< /span>< /p>`

   result in docx:no any background-color
7. `< hr/>`

   result in docx: empty
8. `< table style="border-width:1px;">`...

   result in docx: no border
9. `< span style="font-family: arial , helvetica , sans-serif;font-size: large;">`...

   result in docx: font setting all missed.

Any one know how to deal with these issues? or any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The comment in the [XHTMLImporter source code](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/in/xhtml/XHTMLImporter.java) notes that some of these things remain to be implemented.

Re your #4, I think indent is supported. Maybe just not for the units you have used?

Re your #8 table borders, there is some support for these; Google for other posts.

Implementing underline, delete, and background-color all ought to be straightforward.

If you'd like to do that, we're happy to accept a pull request.

Comment: Thanks for your quickly response. for #4,Could you give me a workable example? for #8, after I changed to < table border="1"> the table border can be shown. for underline,delete,and background-color official support, do you have any time schedule? I can implement it straightforward, but it will cost much time. :-)

Comment: Looking at the code, for margin-left, inches and mm are supported.  No specific plans to work on this right now, although it would be nice to spend a day or 2 on it before the docx4j 3.0 release.

Comment: Current nightlies (and code on GitHub) support underline, and some additional units of measurement for indent.